# FormCollection for a checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My FormCollection is returning back a Checkbox, but I am after the value

```
collection["SelectedCheckbox"]
```

this returns "true,false"

but I want the results, which should be either true or false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in asp.net-mvc you would have to check for  `false`, the reason you check for false because the `Html Checkbox` helper does some kind of freaky thing for value `true`

**True returns as:**

> it makes the string read "true, false"

so you may have thought it was two values but its just one and means true

**False returns as:**

> it makes the string read "false"

Comment: Refer to similar question for more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658458/mvc-html-checkbox-and-form-submit-issue/658514#658514

Comment: if you specify `bool` as parameter instead of reading it as a `string` then it work as expected