# ASP.NET MVC4 FormCollection.GetValues not returning correct values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, formcollection

I'm building a mobile webiste using ASP.NET MVC4.
One of the pages in my solution contains a table where all the rows in the table can be edited and saved in one batch. To do this I am using FormCollection in the Action in the Controller. This works as expected for most of the fields, exept one: item.IsPercent. This field is a boolean, and FormCollection.GetValues("item.IsPercent") returns twice the number of rows in the table and the list always alternates between true and false, no matter what the actual values are.

How can I collect the right value for the Percent checkboxes?

**An Example**

[image]

**My View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(i => i.Exercise.Name)) {
<table>
<tr>
        <th colspan="4">@Html.Label(group.Key)</th>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Load</td>
        <td>Percent</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>Reps</td>
    </tr>
 @foreach (var item in group.OrderBy(i => i.Order))
    {

     @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Load) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Load)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.IsPercent)
        </td>
        <td>
            x
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Repetitions)
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Repetitions)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
    </table>
    <br />
}

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</p>
}
```

**My Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditProgramTemplateLines(FormCollection c)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int ptId = 0;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var ptIdArray = c.GetValues("item.id"); // [1,2,3,4]
            var ptLoadArray = c.GetValues("item.Load"); // [50, 55, 60, 80]
            var ptPercentArray = c.GetValues("item.IsPercent"); // [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false]
            var ptRepsArray = c.GetValues("item.Repetitions"); // [13, 10, 5, 2]

            for (i = 0; i < ptIdArray.Count(); i++) {
                var ptLine = factory.GetProgramTemplateLine(Convert.ToInt32(ptIdArray[i]));
                if(ptId == 0)
                    ptId = ptLine.ProgramTemplateId;

                ptLine.Load = ConvertToDouble(ptLoadArray[i]);
                ptLine.IsPercent = Convert.ToBoolean(ptPercentArray[i]);
                ptLine.Repetitions = ConvertToInt(ptRepsArray[i]);
                factory.SetEntryAsModified(ptLine);

            }
            factory.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = ptId });
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**Updated solution**
Considering the link posted in comment below [FormCollection for a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714989/formcollection-for-a-checkbox) my solution is to loop throug the array like this:

```
var percentId = 0;
for(i = 0;i<ptIdArray.Count();i++){
if(ptPercentArray[percentId] == true){
item.IsPercent = true;
percentId = percentId + 2;
}
else{
item.IsPercent = false;
percentId++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the HTML generated for the `Html.EditorFor`! The helpers create one **checkbox** and one **hidden field** for each checkbox to make state management easily at server side! Thats the problem! Using `FormCollection` as parameter you need to differentiate the hidden from the real checkbox to get the value!

Hopes this help you!

Comment: Hi, thanx a lot! But how can I get the checkboxes and not the hidden fields value?

Comment: Hi! This post shows what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714989/formcollection-for-a-checkbox