# MVC 3 C#: HTML.Checkbox usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have been searching the posts on the HTML.Checkbox, but I still find that I'm not understanding what I need to do to implement this control.  My goal is to provide a test as to whether or not certain controls on a form were filled out; if so, I want to send "true" back within a FormsCollection to some back-end processing in another class that performs some processing based on the value of the control.

I was thinking that I might set the value of the 'hidden' HTML.Checkbox control (true/false) based on the inputs on the form.

Does this this sound like the correct use of this control? Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Why use a checkbox at all?
Why not just use a normal hidden, a string is being sent back to the server either way?
Unless you plan on showing the checkbox to the user, it doesn't matter what the control looks like.

Comment: There is a legacy application that builds an email output based on a Formscollection.  I am trying to pass in control-value pair into that logic.

Comment: One issue with the MVC checkbox is that it sends 2 values back. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658458/mvc-html-checkbox-and-form-submit-issue) One to ensure the Form has a value, the other true/false for value of the check.

Comment: In reviewing the syntax, do the NAME and ID have to be the same?

Comment: no, but the name is sent back in the forms collection. id is client side

Comment: I agree with @Brian, Susan, just use a hidden field to accomplish this.  After all, a checkbox and hidden field both get serialized into a string when sent from the browser to the server so it has no special value... except that the checkbox is automatically made into a Boolean via Binding.

Answer (score 0):

In controller you have use [Httppost] and Form Collection and get the check box valueand keep it in view data or View bag and pass it to view other wise you have to keep in session that check box value in controller and use in any page entire your app.